# Unable to replace text Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframecode . There is a `[UID]` word. I want that word to be replaced with my desired word.

```
<iframe class="ofrss" src="https://wall.superrewards.com/super/offers?h=asacgrgerger&uid=[UID]" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="550px"></iframe>
```

I want to pass the `UID` from jquery .

```
$("body:contains('UID')").html('15');
```

But this code doesn't give me the exact thing I want. It's not replacing the UID with 15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:contains` looks within the text of the DOM, not attributes.

To do what you require you can use `prop()` or `attr()`, like this:

```
$('iframe.ofrss').prop('src', function(i, src) {
  return src.replace('[UID]', '15');
});
```

One thing to note here is that changing the `src` after the DOM loads will cause the `iframe` to be reloaded.

Comment: Thank you so much.. You just saved my two days .. Thank you so much